# Erro NHibernate System.InvalidCastException - ManyToOneType to ComponentType

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType' no tipo 'NHibernate.Type.ComponentType'.

---

As classes envolvidas são:

```
public class ClassePrincipal
{
    public virtual long Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual string Atributo1 { get; set; }
    public virtual EEnumeradorAbstrato EnumeradorAbstrato { get; set; }
    public virtual SubClasse SubClasse { get; set; }
}

public class SubClasse
{
    public virtual string Atributo1 { get; set; }
    public virtual double Atributo2 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Bi-direcionamento
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ClassePrincipal ClassePrincipal { get; set; }
}
```

---

Os mapeamentos:

```
public class ClassePrincipalMap : ClassMap<ClassePrincipal>
{
    public ClassePrincipalMap()
    {
        Table("tb_classe_principal");

        Id(ClassePrincipal => ClassePrincipal.Codigo)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Column("pk_classe_principal")
            .GeneratedBy.Sequence("tb_classe_principal_pk_classe_principal_seq");

        Map(a => a.Atributo1).Column("atributo1");

        Component(ClassePrincipal => ClassePrincipal.EnumeradorAbstrato, 
            componentPart =>
                componentPart.Map(eEnumeradorAbstrato => eEnumeradorAbstrato.Identificador, 
                "enumerador_abstrato"));

        HasOne(ClassePrincipal => ClassePrincipal.SubClasse)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Constrained()
            .ForeignKey("fk_classe_principal");
    }
}

public class SubClasseMap : ClassMap<SubClasse>
{
    public SubClasseMap()
    {
        Table("tb_SubClasse");

        Id(SubClasse => SubClasse.ClassePrincipal.Codigo)
            .Column("fk_classe_principal")
            .GeneratedBy.Foreign("ClassePrincipal.Codigo");

        Map(SubClasse => SubClasse.Atributo1).Column("atributo1");
        Map(SubClasse => SubClasse.Atributo2).Column("atributo2");

        References(SubClasse => SubClasse.ClassePrincipal, "fk_classe_principal").Cascade.None();
    }
}
```

Especificações:

- No banco de dados a fk_classe_principal em tb_SubClasse é a primary_key;
- O erro surgiu depois de eu adicionar a anotação ".GeneratedBy.Foreign("ClassePrincipal.Codigo");".
- O mesmo ocorre quando eu invoco o método session.Save() logo após o 
  "select nextval('sequencia');"

Obrigado.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas o seu modelo diz que a FK: `fk_classe_principal`, também seria a PK na tabela `tb_SubClasse`, certo? E você gostaria de mapear isso para o NHibernate?

Comment: Isso, percebi que o erro realmente acontece devido a anotação: ".GeneratedBy.Foreign("ClassePrincipal.Codigo");".

Estou tentando implementar o GeneratedBy.HiLo() para ver o comportamento. Você sabe como funciona?

Pois dessa tabela que está "ao redor" da principal será inserida primeiro, e o id dela tem que ser o mesmo da principal.

Comment: Postei uma resposta, com a possível solução que acredito funcionar para você, verifique se está adequado ao seu problema e se o soluciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fernando consegui resolver o problema. Realmente era a anotação:`.Cascade.All();`

As classes de modelo continuaram iguais, o que mudou foram as classes mapeadoras.

```
public class ClassePrincipalMap : ClassMap<ClassePrincipal>
{
    public ClassePrincipalMap()
    {
        Table("tb_classe_principal");

        Id(ClassePrincipal => ClassePrincipal.Codigo)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Column("pk_classe_principal")
            .GeneratedBy.Sequence("tb_classe_principal_pk_classe_principal_seq");

        Map(a => a.Atributo1).Column("atributo1");

        Component(ClassePrincipal => ClassePrincipal.EnumeradorAbstrato, 
            componentPart =>
                componentPart.Map(eEnumeradorAbstrato => eEnumeradorAbstrato.Identificador, 
                "enumerador_abstrato"));

        HasOne(ClassePrincipal => ClassePrincipal.SubClasse)
            // ALTERADO
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .ForeignKey("fk_classe_principal");
    }
}

public class SubClasseMap : ClassMap<SubClasse>
{
    public SubClasseMap()
    {
        Table("tb_SubClasse");

        Id(SubClasse => SubClasse.ClassePrincipal.Codigo)
            .Column("fk_classe_principal");

        Map(SubClasse => SubClasse.Atributo1).Column("atributo1");
        Map(SubClasse => SubClasse.Atributo2).Column("atributo2");

        References(SubClasse => SubClasse.ClassePrincipal, "fk_classe_principal")
        // ALTERADO
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

O erro foi resolvido alterando `.Cascade.All()` para `.Cascade.SaveUpdate();`.
Fiz isso tanto na `ClassePrincipal` quanto na(s) `SubClasse`.

Desta forma o NHibernate insere a ClassePrincipal (classe-pai) primeiro e depois as SubClasses (classes-filhas).

Obrigado pelas dicas!

Comment: Legal que resolveu Pedro, bom saber que era esse o problema, isso pode me ajudar no futuro!

Answer (score 1):

Se o meu comentário a pergunta é verdadeiro, você deseja mapear uma FK (`SubClasse.ClassePrincipal.Codigo`), como FK e também com PK, na `SubClasse`, certo?

Eu já tive esse problema a tempos atrás e encontrei [essa excelente solução no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3635182/2290538).

Para mapear uma FK também como PK (unica e simples), você tem fazer o seguinte:

```
public SubClasseMap()
{
    Table("tb_SubClasse");

    // essas duas linhas subsequentes fazem a magica, explicada no link e já adaptada para o seu caso

    // aqui ele mapeia a propriedade/atributo como Id normalmente, sem especificar nenhuma estrategia de geração de Id, já que não há! (talvez a estrategia que se adequaria a esse cenário seria `Assigned`, mas não é necessario)
    Id(SubClasse  => SubClasse.ClassePrincipal.Codigo).Column("fk_classe_principal");
    // aqui estamos mapeando a propriedade como referencia, já se trata de uma chave estrangeira, e o `ReadOnly` é o grande ponto, onde o **NHibernate** não tenta fazer nada com essa propriedade no momento de persistir, deixando para o Id, a persista na base de dados evitando conflitos. (na verdade sem o `ReadOnly` gera uma exceção). 
    References(SubClasse  => SubClasse.ClassePrincipal).Column("fk_classe_principal").ReadOnly();

    // ...
}
```

**Edit**

Há a necessidade de se fazer um hack, na sua `class` na `SubClasse`, já que o NHibernate tenta procurar por um campo chamado "Codigo" em sua classe, então você tem que fazer isso:

```
public virtual long Codigo {
    get { return ClassePrincipal.Codigo ; }
    set { /* O set não precisa ser implementado */ }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Talvez você deva ter que abandonar a abordagem de `Cascade.All()` no mapeamento de sua `ClassePrincipal`, e fazer esse comportamento do cascade na mão:

```
public ClassePrincipalMap()
{
    Table("tb_classe_principal");

    // ...

    // remover essa parte do mapeamento
    /* HasOne(ClassePrincipal => ClassePrincipal.SubClasse)
        .Cascade.All()
        .Constrained()
        .ForeignKey("fk_classe_principal"); */
}
```

No momento de persistir as entidade pode fazer algo nessa linha:

```
// criando objetos para exemplo
ClassePrincipal classePrincipal = new ClassePrincipal();
classePrincipal.Atributo1 = "Attributo 1";
SubClasse subClasse = new SubClasse();
subClasse.Atributo1 = "Sub 1";
subClasse.Atributo2 = 2.0d;
classePrincipal.SubClasse = subClasse;

// --- salvando objetos

// persiste a classe principal
Session.Save(classePrincipal);

// popula a subclasse interna da classe principal com a classePrincipal recém persistida e com o codigo já gerado (talvez haja forma melhor de fazer isso, mas é só para fins de exemplo)
classePrincipal.SubClasse.ClassePrincipal = classePrincipal;

// persiste agora a sub classe, já que não há mais a configuração de cascade
Session.Save(classePrincipal.SubClasse);
```

Comment: Fernando, o NHibernate acusa valor nulo para a fk_classe_principal no momento da inserção. Preciso fazer alguma alteração no modelo?

O insert onde ocorre o erro é este: 
"INSERT INTO tb_subclasse (atributo1, atributo2) VALUES (?, ?); select lastval()";   

Acho que está perto de funcionar :)

Comment: Perdão, agora que vi o Edit. Fiz o teste dessa forma e ele dá NullReferenceException assim que eu inicio o sistema.

Se eu fizer um construtor para a subclasse instanciando um objeto do tipo classe principal funciona?

public subclasse() { ClassePrincipal = new ClassePrincipal(); }

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem o que pode estar acontecendo, mas acredito que seja por que em meu caso, não utilizo `.Cascade.All()` na classe Pai, e vi que você está utilizando, talvez se você puder remover o `HasOne` do mapeamento da `ClassePrincipal` e fazer a inserção da classe `SubClasse` na mão logo após inserir o `ClassePrincipal`, setando a atributo da sub classe informando a `ClassePrincipal` recem salva talvez já funcione.

Comment: Certo, farei esse teste agora

Comment: @Pedro, confira a edição na resposta, com detalhes do meu comentário anterior.

Comment: Ok, vou fazer as alterações necessárias e testar. Logo postarei o resultado